# Quicksight Calculated field: sum of average?

Tags: data-visualization, amazon-quicksight

The dataset I have is currently like so:

| country | itemid | device | num_purchases | total_views_per_country_and_day | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | ABC | iPhone11 | 2 | 900 | 2022-06-15 |
| USA | ABC | iPhoneX | 5 | 900 | 2022-06-15 |
| USA | DEF | iPhoneX | 8 | 900 | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | ABC | iPhone11 | 10 | 350 | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | DEF | iPhone11 | 20 | 350 | 2022-06-15 |

`total_views_per_country_and_day` is already pre-calculated to be the sum grouped by country and day. That is why for each country-day pair, the number is the same.

I have a Quicksight analysis with a filter for day.

The first thing I want is to have a table on my dashboard that shows the number of total views for each country.

However, if I were to do it with the dataset just like that, the table would sum everything:

| country | total_views |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 900+900+900=2700 |
| UK | 350+350=700 |

So what I did was, create a calculated field which is the average of total_views. Which worked---but only if my `day` filter on dashboard was for ONE day.

When filtered for day = 2022-06-15: **correct**

| country | avg(total_views) |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 2700/3=900 |
| UK | 700/2=350 |

But let's say we have data from 2022-06-16 as well, the averaging method doesn't work, because it will average based on the entire dataset. So, example dataset with two days:

| country | itemid | device | num_purchases | total_views_per_country_and_day | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | ABC | iPhone11 | 2 | 900 | 2022-06-15 |
| USA | ABC | iPhoneX | 5 | 900 | 2022-06-15 |
| USA | DEF | iPhoneX | 8 | 900 | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | ABC | iPhone11 | 10 | 350 | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | DEF | iPhone11 | 20 | 350 | 2022-06-15 |
| USA | ABC | iPhone11 | 2 | 1000 | 2022-06-16 |
| USA | ABC | iPhoneX | 5 | 1000 | 2022-06-16 |
| UK | ABC | iPhone11 | 10 | 500 | 2022-06-16 |
| UK | DEF | iPhone11 | 20 | 500 | 2022-06-16 |

Desired Table Visualization:

| country | total_views |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 900 + 1000 = 1900 |
| UK | 350 + 500 = 850 |

USA calculation: (900 * 3)/3 + (1000 * 2) /2 = 900 + 1000

UK calculation: (350 * 2) /2 + (500 * 2) /2 = 350 + 500

Basically---a sum of averages.

However, instead it is calculated like:

| country | avg(total_views) |
| --- | --- |
| USA | [(900 * 3) + (1000*2)] / 5 = 940 |
| UK | [(350 * 2) + (500 * 2)] / 4 = 425 |

I want to be able to use this calculation later on as well to calculate num_purchases / total_views. So ideally I would want it to be a calculated field. Is there a formula that can do this?

I also tried, instead of calculated field, just aggregating total_views by average instead of sum in the analysis -- exact same issue, but I could actually keep a running total if I include day in the table visualization. E.G.

| country | day | running total of avg(total_views) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 2022-06-15 | 900 |
| USA | 2022-06-16 | 900+1000=1900 |
| UK | 2022-06-15 | 350 |
| UK | 2022-06-16 | 350+500=850 |

So you can see that the total (2nd and 4th row) is my desired value. However this is not exactly what I want.. I don't want to have to add the day into the table to get it right.

I've tried avgOver with day as a partition, that also requires you to have `day` in the table visualization.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum({total_views_per_country_and_day}) / distinct_count( {day})
```

Basically your average is calculated as sum of metric divided by number of unique days. The above should help.